# Is this implementation correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock, synchronized

I was wondering if this implementation is correct.

The scenario is:

- one overseer
- unknown number of workers (0-n)
- overseer only needs to convey `resume work` or `production has stopped` signals to the workers
- workers handle checks on data themselves, so even a few redundant `resume work` signals without any new data present are acceptable (so this is basically just to reduce busy waiting to a minimum, not guaranteed to 100% avoid it)
- workers also **DO NOT rival** over data. Data is not consumed but simply more data present that *can* be processed. (If there was consumption, I'd use semaphores or BlockingQueues)
- It is not necessary for any worker to receive every `resume work` signal (or not even one): if they missed one, the next one will come along. Even if they missed all, the only thing that MUST happen is that the  `production has stopped` signal from `.signalEnd()` is received by all.

Using `signalEnd()`, this should also prevent a missed `Thread.notify()`: in case the `notify`ing Thread was run before the `wait`ing Thread.

Code:

```
package jc.lib.lang.thread;

/**
 * Worker Threads wait for signals from Overseer Threads.<br>
 * <ul>
 * <li>Workers wait for data ({@link #awaitProgress(long, int)}), work, wait again for more data. Can re-enlist multiple times.</li>
 * <li>Overseers send {@link #signalProgress()} if they made more data available.</li>
 * <li>Overseers signal end ({@link #signalEnd()}) to indicate that no more data will be available.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author jc
 * @since 2023-07-20
 */
public final class JcCyclicLatch {

    private final Object mSyncObject = new Object();

    private volatile boolean mWorkEnded = false;

    public JcCyclicLatch() {}



    /**
     * Worker Threads wait for Overseer Thread to signal new data.
     * @return <b>true</b> if new data is present (continue working).<br> <b>false</b> if work has been completed (stop working).
     * @see {@linkplain Object#wait(long, int)}
     */
    public boolean awaitProgress(final long pTimeoutMs, final int pTimeoutNs) {
        if (mWorkEnded) return false;

        synchronized (mSyncObject) {
            try {
                if (mWorkEnded) return false;
                mSyncObject.wait(pTimeoutMs, pTimeoutNs);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) { /* cannot happen, we ourselves control the sync object */ }
        }
        return !mWorkEnded;
    }
    /**
     * @see #awaitProgress(long, int)
     */
    public boolean awaitProgress(final long pTimeoutMs) {
        return awaitProgress(pTimeoutMs, 0);
    }
    /**
     * @see #awaitProgress(long, int)
     */
    public boolean awaitProgress() {
        return awaitProgress(0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Overseer Thread signals availability of new data.
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public void signalProgress() {
        synchronized (mSyncObject) {
            mSyncObject.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Break open lock so that all registered Workers will pass. Future Workers will also pass rigth through.
     */
    public void signalEnd() {
        mWorkEnded = true;
        signalProgress();
    }

    /**
     * Resets to inital status.
     */
    public void reset() {
        mWorkEnded = false;
    }



    /*
     * Example method
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JcCyclicLatch l = new JcCyclicLatch();

        // start workerss
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            final Thread workerThread = new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("C " + index + " started.");
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("C " + index + " waiting...");
                    final boolean continueWorking = l.awaitProgress();

                    // we could put an early if(!continueWork) break here, if we do not need to process all data

                    // ... work stuff
                    System.out.println("C " + index + " working.");
                    // ... work stuff

                    if (!continueWorking) { // here, we have processed all (available) data
                        System.out.println("C " + index + " is done working.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("C " + index + " ending.");
            });
            workerThread.start();
        }

        // this is the overseer
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("P working...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // simulates work
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) { /* */ }

            System.out.println("P has new data.");
            l.signalProgress();
        }
        System.out.println("P is ending...");
        l.signalEnd();
        System.out.println("P finished.");
    }

}
```

If there was only 1 overseer and 1 worker involved, I'd resort to a `LinkedBlockingQueue` that would contain data packets and finally a special package to signal `production has stopped`.

So my actual question is, **if that implementation is correct and/or should/could be further improved** regarding the following aspects:

- does it prevent locking up (as possible with `obj.wait()` after `obj.notify()`) as far as `.signalEnd()` is concerned?
- does it *reduce* busy waiting?

Additional questions, collecting opinions here, consider in the answer or comment on it:

1. As this is such as basic scenario, is there any default java class that accomplishes this in equal small code complexity?
2. I am not sure if the name `CyclicLatch` is a proper fit. Between all the `Latch`es and `Lock`s and `Barrier`s and `Sempahore`s and `Phaser`s I'm getting quite confused. What would you name it?

Comment: Haven't looked in depth, but your "consumer" calls `wait` unconditionally,  and not in a loop, so probably not OK. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Re, "consumers also DO NOT rival over data. Data is not consumed." Sounds like maybe "producer/consumer" might not be the right name for your algorithm.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanx for the answers. The loop is not necessary for my needs, because a) I control the `mSyncObject` myself (not public), so wrong signalling is unlikely. And then again, c) IF someone used reflection to access and `.notify()` my sync object, it would simply let the 'consumers' check state once too often. In that case, they'd simlpy check their input, decide there's nothing to do, and jump into the `.awaitProgress()` again. You are right in the 'Producer'/'Consumer' thingy. I'll rename them to `Overseer` and `Worker`.

Comment: You're right. I did not look deeply. I only looked at the instance methods, and I assumed that `main()` was just "test code." So your consumers _do_ call `wait` in a loop even though the loop and the `wait` happen to be in different methods. Also, it appears (but I _still_ haven't looked _really_ deeply) that there's no way for a consumer to `wait` after the last `notifyAll` has happened. There's several reasons why I would not give your code a "pass" in a code-review situation, but they're all about [the ilities](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ility), not about correctness.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this code does what you want in this case:

1. Worker starts working....
2. Overseer calls `signalProgress`
3. Worker finishes and calls `awaitProgress`

At this point, I believe you want the worker to be working, but it is not, because it missed the signal.  You should not try to use `notify...` to convey state information.  Only use it to notify waiters when the state changes.

You really need to have a `boolean workersEnabled;` or similar that you guard with `mSyncObject`.

Comment: Thanx for the input, I updated the question: *It is not necessary for all workers to receive every resume work signal: if they missed one, the next one will come along. The only thing that MUST happen is that the `production has stopped` signal from .signalEnd() is received by all.* And say, if I had `boolean workersEnabled;` to signal that, I would have another 'soft' problem: to reset `workersEnabled=false` in the producer AFTER all workers started but BEFORE any one worker has finished working.

Comment: What if *all* the workers miss the signal?

Comment: Since you provided all your code, I'll add a fix.  When you write concurrent code, you have to try hard to make it easy to prove that it works, because anyone who reads that code needs to do that proof in their head.

Comment: The final signal of any Overseer will be `.signalEnd()`, which all workers MUST receive. The `.signalProcess()` is expected to come frequently, like reading from a socket  or waiting on the output of another process. And if that is too fast for the workers, they will (MUST) receive the `.signalEnd()`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't see how any of the workers recognize that they should pause.  I guess I can't add a fix, because the recognition that work has run out needs to be inside the guard.  Alternatively, you can keep a "progress" count, but that will change your interface significantly.

Comment: Re signalling...  what if all the workers miss the *last* progress signal.  Doesn't that mean that there is some work that won't get done?

Comment: In my code, in the exmaple `main()`, there is the line `if (!continueWorking) break;` that lets the workers exit the loop early. If they needed to finish processing all data, then they'd simply have the `work` block before the `if(...) break` block.

Comment: In my comment just above, I assume you're talking of the `.signalProcess()` signal. If they missed the `.signalEnd()` signal, that would be devastating.